# Site icon in migration dialog is mispositioned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, vote-to-close

The site icon on the off-topic close dialog doesn't line up with the text:

[image: Screenshot of the UL close dialog]

The only other sites I can close on are SO and BCG (which is still in beta); the icons look right on those:

[image: Screenshot of the SO close dialog]

[image: Screenshot of the BCG close dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was some poor [CSS-S-S-S'ing](http://vimeo.com/3718294) on my part - fixed.

<sub>Most of my css is poor, though!</sub>